# How to publish the default workflow(github action) to git hub marketplace?

Tags: yaml, github-actions, marketplace

I have a GitHub action that contains some npm and gulp commands and finally runs a Powershell file. I want to publish this GitHub action on the marketplace so that my team can use it. I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere. I checked the publish Github actions docs, there is no related document.

How do I invoke this action externally?

For instance, How do I convert this simple action so that it can be published to the marketplace?

Sample yml code

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '10.x'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yaml you've posted here is a *workflow*, not an action. An action is the code behind the things like `uses: actions/checkout@v2` (usually JavaScript, can be Dockerized too). If you're only writing YAML, you're just writing a workflow that *invokes* actions.

If you want to make your own action, check out the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions).